# multiple reports on the same page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a 5.5 x 11 report. I would like to print 2 reports side by side on the same page (ex invoice #1 on the left and invoice #2 on the right). Can this be done? I am using crystal reports for VB 2010.

Comment: yes it can be done.. use sub reports side by side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can must create a main report and insert all common data of the invoices that you want to insert in the body of this summary.
Then create a subreport with the data of each invoice and insert it a section of the main report